# Query SQLAlchemy Time to Pandas Time (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, sqlalchemy

I am trying to query a SQLalchemy table to a Pandas dataframe and match the times up. There is no date, just time. Basically I just need to find the record in the database that matches the time from my Pandas dataframe.

Release Table is basically just this:

```
class Release_Table(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Release_Table'

    id = Column('Id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    release_time = Column('release_time', Time)
```

And the datatype of df['release'] is dtype('O')

So I am doing this:

```
for i in df.index:
     release = session.query(Release_Table).filter(Release_Table.release_time == df.loc[i,'release']).first()
     df.loc[i, 'release'] = release.id
```

When I do this, I get this error:

ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]The data types time and datetime2 are incompatible in the equal to operator. (402) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)')

If I try to convert df.loc[i, 'release'] to datetime, it says:

TypeError:  is not convertible to datetime

So I don't know how to compare these two times. Both data types are datetime.time from what I can tell, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information.  What is `Release_Table`?  Also, please show the dtypes of the df: `df.dtypes`

Comment: Updated with more information.

Comment: `df.loc[i,'release'].time()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out. I just needed to do this:

```
for i in df.index:
     release = session.query(Release_Table).filter(Release_Table.release_time == str(df.loc[i,'release'])).first()
     df.loc[i, 'release'] = release.id
```

Turning it into a string solved it for me. I'll leave this here in case anyone else stumbles upon this problem.